# Customize stroke width of land

Tags: javascript, d3.js, planetary.js

The [Planetary JS Earth plugin](http://planetaryjs.com/documentation/builtin_earth.html) takes a config object that can define fill and stroke colors for oceans, land, and border. Unfortunately, the docs don’t give any information about can be passed into the configs for each of these. I’d like to control the stroke width of the borders, something like this:

```
const lightGray = 'rgb(222,224,223)';
const lightBlue = 'rgb(160,205,226)';
const blue = 'rgb(144,182,203)';
planet.loadPlugin(
  planetary.plugins.earth({
    topojson: {world: topojson},
    oceans: {fill: lightBlue},

    /* strokeWidth is ignored: */
    borders: {stroke: blue, strokeWidth: '5px'},

    land: {fill: lightGray, stroke: blue},
  })
);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It's `stroke-width`, with hyphen and lowercase w.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I tried that (`borders: {stroke: blue, 'stroke-width': '5px'}`) but it didn't work either. Both with and without the `px` units.

Comment: I just read the docs and they don't use the regular CSS nomenclature, so it could be in fact `strokeWidth`. However, there is no `strokeWidth` in the docs... why don't you simply set a class and use the CSS (which is `stroke-width`) for styling this?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado It paints into a <canvas>, so I can’t target painted items with CSS, as they have no DOM element.

Comment: Oh, I see. Indeed, you can't set CSS styles in a canvas. A last question: did you try `lineWidth`?

Comment: Hey, it works! `lineWidth` and a value with no units (`lineWidth: '5'`). Thanks. Throw that in an Answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://planetaryjs.com/documentation/builtin_borders.html), it has to be `lineWidth`, and the value has to be a number, with no units.

Here is an example:

```
planetaryjs.plugins.borders({
    stroke: '#008000', lineWidth: 0.25
});
```